# How can i have different mass on same object?

Tags: physics

So, I am building a project that has double pendulum, like one pendulum attached to another pendulum...
So i created a cylinder and scaled it up and made it like a thin long rod and then i added a sphere (while being in edit mode) and made a bob of pendulum, then i gave a rigid body simulation to it... i wanted the rod to have different mass and the bob tho have different mass. how can i do that?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Getting mass is easy.  You apply rigid body in physics menu then open the setting arrow in it. The default is 1kg but you can change this to particular materials eg lead in the object>rigid body>calculate mass menu option. This works well and I've built complex shapes using micro cubes like lego/mineworld and then hot their masses and simulated them.

I too would like advice on best approach to double pendulum. I tried 3 UV Sphere connected by nurb paths extending the many youtube  simple pendulum Blender examples.  I can only get the middle ball to swing and one nurb path just gets stuck locking the second pendulum.  Did you complete? I wish some guru would show how its best done...